# Java interface design: where should I put a lot of duplicate code that will be used by all subclasses?

Tags: java, interface, subclass

```
interface Tuple {
    void method1();
}

class Tuple1 implements Tuple {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // some code ....
        utilityMethod();
        // some code ....
    }

    // it will be used by subclasses of Tuple only
    private void utilityMethod(){ 
        // some code....
    }
}

class Tuple2 implements Tuple {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // some code ....
        utilityMethod();
        // some code ....
    }

    // it will be used by subclasses of Tuple only
    private void utilityMethod(){
        // some code....
    }
}
```

the `utilityMethod` will be used by **all subclasses** of `Tuple`, where should I put the `utilityMethod` best?

Comment: Tuple1? Isn't that just an object?

Comment: What does the method _do_?

Comment: From the names, I'm guessing that `Tuple` should actually be an abstract class, rather than an interface.  Then all you need to do is declare this method as protected.

Answer (score 2):

Absent some compelling reasons, I would put it in `Tuple`. You can make it a default method. Like,

```
interface Tuple {
    void method1();
    // it will be used by subclasses of Tuple only
    default void utilityMethod(){ 
        // some code....
    }
}
```